How to use openssl ro decrypt AES-256-CBC file that was created with a binary passphrase
# decrypt binary file.enc
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in file.enc -out file.txt

I generated a encrypted file using AES-256-CBC using a PHP library. The library generates and stores the file in binary format and so is the passphrase (also in binary format). I am able to use this to decrypt the file using the same library, but in unsure how to decrypt using the above command on a Mac. How do I specify the binary passphrase?
